# Best $g$ Approximation Poset maps

Tags: examples-counterexamples, order-theory

Let $P, Q$ be posets, $g: P\rightarrow Q$ be a monotone map. Let $x\in Q$. By a $g$-approximation of $x$ we mean an element $y\in P$ with $x\leq g(y)$. A best $g$-approximation of $x$ is a $g$-approximation $y$ of $x$ so that for any $z\in P$ with $x\leq g(z)$, $y\leq z$.

Find an example of posets $P$, $Q$ and a surjective monotone map $g:P\rightarrow Q$ such that some $x\in Q$ does not have a best $g$-approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P = (\mathbb{R}, \le)$ and $Q = (\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}, \le)$. Define $g : P \to Q$ by $g(x) = \text{e}^x$. Then $0 \in Q$ has no best approximation by $g$.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant to ask for a surjective monotone map, not just some generic monotone map. It's easy to come up with those examples. Maybe there's an easy example with $g$ being epi too, but I can't think of one.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but it seems that if you require surjectivity, the situation is trivially _impossible_. Consider any $x \in Q$. Then, $g^{-1}(x) \neq \emptyset$ via surjectivity and _every_ $y \in g^{-1}(x)$ is a best approximation to $x$ by $g$. For, given $z \in P$, if $z < y$, then $g(z) < g(y) = x$ via monotonicity. Am I missing something?